# Lollipop - Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions

Tags: android, fragmentmanager

I've got the  `"Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions"` error after trying to  call `fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()` method.

Does anyone has a solution for it?

This occurs only on android 5.1, on other platform it works as expected.
Please, let me know, what else fropm source code I should give you to understand the question

Many thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case it reproduce only on 5.1. cause onAttach(Context context) method doesn't call on Android API < 23. So I've init contect in that method and when I try to open new fragment, it can't